# Add up Total Cumulative Hours, Minutes, Seconds from shift times for all agents in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, datediff

I need to calculate total 'Logged in' times for all agents.

```
+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+  
|ShiftDateAndTime       |EmployeeID   |LoginTime              |LogoutTime             |  
+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+  
|2017-03-07 08:59:56.000|   81200     |2017-03-07 08:59:56.000|2017-03-07 17:30:43.000|  
+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+  
|2017-03-07 07:35:12.000|   82300     |2017-03-07 07:35:12.000|2017-03-07 16:04:30.000|  
+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+  
|2017-03-07 09:38:58.000|   81800     |2017-03-07 09:38:58.000|2017-03-07 18:02:59.000|  
+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+  
|2017-03-07 09:18:52.000|   83240     |2017-03-07 09:18:52.000|2017-03-07 18:08:54.000|  
+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

I want to calculate total cumulative man hours for 2017-03-07 across all agents. For example,

```
Sum(LogoutTime - LoginTime for Agent1, Agent2, Agent3 and Agent4.)
```

I need the time in `hh:mm:ss`. I'm using SQL Server 2014 to run the query.

I have tried:

> SELECT
>        (SUM (datediff(second, LoginTime, LogoutTime)) / 3600) [TotalTime]
>       FROM AgentStats

But I only get the time in minutes. I need it in hh:mm:ss.

Comment: Sorry...
I have tried:
  SELECT
   (SUM (datediff(second, LoginTime, LogoutTime)) / 3600) [TotalTime]
  FROM AgentStats
  GROUP BY ShiftDateAndTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a CTE just to make it easy to format the result as HH:MM:SS

```
WITH acm AS
(
    SELECT   SUM (DATEDIFF(second, LoginTime, LogoutTime)) [Seconds]
    FROM     @AgentStats
    WHERE    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ShiftDateAndTime)) = CAST('2017-03-07' AS DATETIME)
)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Seconds/3600)  
       +':' 
       + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),(Seconds%3600)/60),2) 
       +':' 
       + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),Seconds%60),2) AS [HH:MM:SS]
FROM   acm;
```

The result is:

```
HH:MM:SS
34:14:08
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/EHCSY33410

You don't need to group by ShiftDateAndTime due you're selecting only one day.

**UPDATE**

I'd suggest to create an INLINE User Defined Function just to make it shorter and easy to use on a big queries.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SecondsToHMS(@Seconds int)
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @Seconds / 3600) + ':' 
           + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (@Seconds % 3600) / 60) ,2) + ':' 
           + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @Seconds%60), 2) AS [HMS]
);

GO
```

Then previous query can be changed to:

```
SELECT   (SELECT HMS FROM dbo.SecondsToHMS(SUM (DATEDIFF(second, LoginTime, LogoutTime)))) [HMS]
FROM     @AgentStats
WHERE    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ShiftDateAndTime)) = CAST('2017-03-07' AS DATETIME)
GO

/*
|HMS     |
|:-------|
|34:14:08|
*/
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=dfb806641a67d6e15cacbe4b53fe9eeb)*

Comment: I get an error message.  
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'Seconds'.

I think you missed a , after EMployeeID. Even after adding that comma, I get the error message.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the extra parenthesis from the left but I get the results as follows:     
+--------------+----------------+
|EmployeeID    | HH:MM:SS       |
+--------------+----------------+
| 8122        | 7:00:0*        |
+--------------+----------------+
| 8214        | 6:00:0*        |
+--------------+----------------+
| 8220         | 8:00:0*        |
+--------------+----------------+


But that can't be right. My login times and logout times are wildly irregular.

Comment: Also, I needed the cumulative total hours and minutes of all the agents together. So I would need to group by The Shift Date

Comment: Last Question, sir. >>  How would I add this query in my other bigger query?
Eg:   Select field1, field2, field3, (WITH acm AS (......)  FROM   acm;) HH:MM:SS   
From BiggerQueryTable

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.